# Href not navigating to respective page

Tags: html, href

```
            <div class="footer_links">

               <ul class="foot">
                   <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#companyVision">Company Vision<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#mgtTeam">Management Team<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#indLeadership">Industry Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#ThoughtLead">Thought Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="../offerings/offer.html">Offerings<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="../contactus/contact.html">Contact Us<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               </ul>

           </div>
```

In the above code i have 4 footer links which will navigate to the respective pages. Assume i clicked on "company vision" it'll navigate. but after that if i click on any other links its not navigating. The footers are same for all the pages. I was checking the click event is happening or not, it was not detecting after navigating to the link. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: When i click on some link respective URL will be displayed but not navigating

Comment: The problem is once you have navigate to Company Vision page the following path in footer `../about_us/about.html#companyVision` will try to find your page in wrong a place in your next click. So you have to update your footer for inner pages. like `<a href="about.html#mgmtTeam">`

Comment: See console for error. Press F12 in Chrome or Right click and go to inspect HTML element then go to console.

Comment: No errors.. In console

Answer (score 0):

The problem here will be that, the first time no matter which of the about.html#???? you click the first time it will work. but no the clicks after the first one as you are already on the about.html page so let assume this:

#### you have this menu in the index.html(same menu you have post)

```
<div class="footer_links">

           <ul class="foot">
               <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#companyVision">Company Vision<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#mgtTeam">Management Team<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#indLeadership">Industry Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../about_us/about.html#ThoughtLead">Thought Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../offerings/offer.html">Offerings<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../contactus/contact.html">Contact Us<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           </ul>

       </div>
```

#### but in the about.html page you will change it to

```
<div class="footer_links">

           <ul class="foot">
               <li><a href="#companyVision">Company Vision<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#mgtTeam">Management Team<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#indLeadership">Industry Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#ThoughtLead">Thought Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../offerings/offer.html">Offerings<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="../contactus/contact.html">Contact Us<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           </ul>

       </div>
```

but finally i will recommend to change your file/folder structure

#### from:

- sitefolder/

  - index.html
  - about_us/

    - about.html
  - offerings/

    - offer.html
  - contactus/

    - contact.html

#### to:

- sitefolder/

  - index.html
  - about.html
  - offer.html
  - contact.html

### So you can have a simpler menu (same for all pages):

```
<div class="footer_links">

       <ul class="foot">
           <li><a href="about.html#companyVision">Company Vision<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html#mgtTeam">Management Team<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html#indLeadership">Industry Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html#ThoughtLead">Thought Leadership<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href="offer.html">Offerings<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us<span class="underline"></span></a></li>
       </ul>

   </div>
```

### After checking in your site, it seems to be using jQuery to load the tabs, so I make it work by adding this on each footer-link

```
onClick="window.location.reload()
```

Comment: I changed as u said in about.html.. still the same issue.. project structure i don't have permission to change

Comment: do you have a link to check the issue??